# problems with js table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my table , I need to put several variable in my table , this is my error

`TypeError: tabproduit[i] is undefined`

`tabproduit[i][0] = $(this).text();`

and this is my code

```
var tabproduit = new Array(new Array());
var i = 0 ;
$( ".eachnom" ).each(function( index ) {
  tabproduit[i][0] = $(this).text();
    i++;
});
```

however , when I don't put the `i++;` I don t have the error but I have just 1 variable in my table;

how to put this `i++;`?

thanks in advance

Comment: use `index` instead of `i`.Its also increment on each function call. like this `tabproduit[index][0]`

Comment: problem is you haven't showed your html part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're getting the error because js provides a single dimensional array in nature you can extend it into two dimensional by the following convention

```
 var s = [[],[],[]]
```

if not then you will get the array [ith] position always undefined

so my suggestion to you would be first get the number of rows then define

s[r1] = [];
s[r2] = []... and so on may be using loop

then you will be able to do s[r1][c1] operation

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

No need for `i` you already get the index from the jQuery method **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)**, just use it :

```
var tabproduit = new Array(new Array());

$( ".eachnom" ).each(function( index ) {
  tabproduit[index][0] = $(this).text();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have always the same error : 
TypeError: tabproduit[index] is undefined
tabproduit[index][0] = $(this).text();

Comment: What's your desired `output`? how you want the array `tabproduit` to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Change `tabproduit[0][index]`

```js
var tabproduit = new Array(new Array());

$( ".eachnom" ).each(function (index) {
  tabproduit[0][index] = $(this).text();
  
});
console.log(tabproduit)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="eachnom">dcbmc</p>
<p class="eachnom">cnc</p>
<p class="eachnom">xcjx</p>
<p class="eachnom">xmcn</p>
<p class="eachnom">xcnx</p>
```

Comment: what it returns ?? `$( ".eachnom" ) ` ? array or object if array then what array thanks

Comment: that works like you but i need to put like this tabproduit[index][0] = $(this).text(); and that does nt work

Comment: just name of product like this : FAUTEUIL RELEV AVALON G4 BEIG

Comment: @weymeels `new array(new array)` is like `1st array[  0th postion of 1st array[ ] ]`  .In code `tabproduit=1st array` `index=0,1,2,3,4,5`. The are load with `[ [ 0,1,2,3,4,5] ]`.so they `tabproduit[index][0] ` is not possible ,revers is possible `tabproduit[0][index]`.What you expecting from this result .can you clarify?

Comment: @Mahi .there was an array .`Array[array]` ,array inside another one array. Match `tabproduit[0]` its indicate with innerArray . `index` is length of the `p tag` its call from classname.`$(this).text()` is get the text value form `p tag` with reference to index match. ex like . `index=3` get the value from 3rd `p tag"xmcn"` its start from `0`.Then all the data load to inner array of `tabproduit`.each loop is act like for loop.`$(this)== $(".eachnom")` for in this case

Answer (score 0):

Since error says "tabproduit[i] is undefined". You have to initialize tabproduit[i] inside the loop.
Try :

```
var tabproduit = new Array(new Array());
var i = 0 ;
$(".eachnom").each(function( index ) {
console.log(index);
tabproduit[i]= new Array();
  tabproduit[i][0] = $(this);
    i++;
});
```

PS: instead of using new Array() it is preferable to use [];

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var tabproduit = [];
var i = 0 ;
$( ".eachnom" ).each(function() {
  tabproduit.push([$(this).text()]);
    i++;
});
```

But I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
var tabproduit = [];
var i = 0 ;
$( ".eachnom" ).each(function() {
  tabproduit.push($(this).text());
    i++;
});
```

Well, this depends on the actual structure of your array.
Cheers..!

Answer (score -2):

This may help you with your code:

```
ar tabproduit = new Array(new Array());

$( ".eachnom" ).each(function( index ) {
  tabproduit[index][0] = $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: Although this might answer the question, it is good style to add an explanation to the code.